# Java gui not showing when I put it in it's own method

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class Calculator1{

    public void Calculator1(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);

        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(4, 3, 10, 10);
        frame.setLayout(grid);

        JLabel op1Label= new JLabel("Operand One:");
        JTextField operandOne = new JTextField();
        operandOne.setText("");
        operandOne.setEditable(true);
        frame.add(op1Label);
        frame.add(operandOne);

        JLabel op2Label = new JLabel("Operand Two:");
        JTextField operandTwo = new JTextField();
        operandTwo.setText("");
        operandTwo.setEditable(true);
        frame.add(op2Label);
        frame.add(operandTwo);

        JButton plus = new JButton("+");
        frame.add(plus);
        JButton minus = new JButton("-");
        frame.add(minus);

        JButton multiply = new JButton("*");
        frame.add(multiply);

        JButton divide = new JButton("/");
        frame.add(divide);

        JButton exponent = new JButton("^");
        frame.add(exponent);

        JButton route = new JButton("\u221A");
        frame.add(route);

        JButton increment = new JButton("Increment");
        frame.add(increment);

        JButton decrement = new JButton("Decrement");
        frame.add(decrement);

        JButton reciprocal = new JButton("Reciprocal");
        frame.add(reciprocal);

        JLabel resultLabel= new JLabel("Result:");
        JTextField result = new JTextField();
        result.setText("0");
        result.setEditable(false);
        frame.add(resultLabel);
        frame.add(result);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator1 calc = new Calculator1();
    }
}
```

I'm really new to Java and trying to program a calculator. The action listeners I'll do after I get the thing to display, I got them to work when it was in the main so it shouldn't be too hard. It shows when I put all of the code into the main but when I try put it in its own method, the program compiles and runs but nothing shows up except the cmd line. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are calling a constructor (using `new`), but your `Calculator1` method is just a method that happens to have the same name as a class, but *not* a constructor for that class, so it uses the default constructor instead. To make it a constructor, remove the `void` return value.

```
public Calculator1() { // without return value it's a constructor
    ...      
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator1 calc = new Calculator1(); // call the constructor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use constructor of your class or use calc.Calculator1().

Answer (score 0):

Change public void Calculator1()  --->  public static void Calculator1()
and call the function in main()

```
public class Calculator1{

public static void Calculator1(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);

    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(4, 3, 10, 10);
    frame.setLayout(grid);

        JLabel op1Label= new JLabel("Operand One:");
        JTextField operandOne = new JTextField();
        operandOne.setText("");
        operandOne.setEditable(true);
        frame.add(op1Label);
        frame.add(operandOne);

        JLabel op2Label = new JLabel("Operand Two:");
        JTextField operandTwo = new JTextField();
        operandTwo.setText("");
        operandTwo.setEditable(true);
        frame.add(op2Label);
        frame.add(operandTwo);

                JButton plus = new JButton("+");
                frame.add(plus);
                JButton minus = new JButton("-");
                frame.add(minus);

                JButton multiply = new JButton("*");
                frame.add(multiply);

                JButton divide = new JButton("/");
                frame.add(divide);

                JButton exponent = new JButton("^");
                frame.add(exponent);

                JButton route = new JButton("\u221A");
                frame.add(route);

                JButton increment = new JButton("Increment");
                frame.add(increment);

                JButton decrement = new JButton("Decrement");
                frame.add(decrement);

                JButton reciprocal = new JButton("Reciprocal");
                frame.add(reciprocal);

                JLabel resultLabel= new JLabel("Result:");
                JTextField result = new JTextField();
                result.setText("0");
                result.setEditable(false);
                frame.add(resultLabel);
                frame.add(result);
                frame.pack();

                frame.setVisible(true);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Calculator1 calc = new Calculator1();
     Calculator1();
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

change  `public void Calculator1(){ /* rest of the code */ }`

as  `public Calculator1(){ /* rest of the code */ }`

Comment: Please edit your answer, and explain why this solves the problem.